# what did I do wrong to get an error in the replace() method?

Tags: java, string, jgrasp

My teacher asked us to design a program that receives a string value and then converts all numeric characters to `*`.

[image: code sample]
I tried the `replaces` method but it did not work.

Comment: Edit your question and post your code as text, not as an image, please.   [Read why](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regular expressions. In addition to that, since you want to replace all numbers, you should use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`. This should do the job:

```
s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "*")
```

Use it to instead of

```
s.replaces(...)
```